# C++ pmr polymorphic memory resources choice supports to release as needed

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, c++17, c++pmr

My program is a daemon and runs for a long time. Only some of the time it will needs a lot of memory resource.

I want to increase my program performance by increasing memory locality.
And PMR seems like a good tool for this purpose.

However, it seems that the memory resources provided by the standard does not return the memory to upstream when there are lots of memory currently not used.
(i.e. synchronized_pool_resource, unsynchronized_pool_resource, monotonic_buffer_resource)

I want that my program can use less memory when the load is not high. (kinds of like calling `malloc_trim` when needed)

Is there a memory resource that will only cache small amount of currenly un-used memory, and  return the rest to upstream.

Comment: "*synchronized_pool_resource, unsynchronized_pool_resource, monotonic_buffer_resource*" The *entire point* of these resources is that they *don't* allocate from the heap. Fast allocation is their goal, and that means only going to the heap at specific, and *knowable* intervals (and you can even prevent that). So them returning memory that is "unused" wouldn't be helpful to their purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory resource can be written to do whatever you want. However, since what you've described (returning memory that is unused) is what the default allocator does (and is one of the main reasons to use it), there wasn't much point in adding more standard library memory resources that do this.

Most of the defined memory resources are all about *not* returning unused memory, because returning and reallocating memory is expensive. They provide different strategies for keeping that memory accessible, so that later allocation calls are as fast as possible. That is, their whole point is to avoid the cost of allocating memory from the heap.

So you'll have to write a resource with the functionality you're looking for.